# how does returning the head gives me the result in a linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the following code, the method returns me the head of the array which is reference of the head of the linkedlist with removed duplicates. What I can't get mind around is how does the head contain that reference when all the pointer changes has been made on current.

```
    public static Node removeDuplicates(Node head)
{
    Node previous = null;
    Node current = head;

    // take an empty set to store linked list nodes for future reference
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    // do till the linked list is empty
    while (current != null)
    {
        // if the current node is seen before, ignore it
        if (set.contains(current.data)) {
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        else {
            // insert the current node into the set and proceed to the next node
            set.add(current.data);
            previous = current;
        }
        current = previous.next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linked list

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> null
```

Traversing the list, starting at `head`, we get `A,B,C,D` in that order.

Let `current` be `B`, and you remove the next node (ie. `C`), so `B.next = D`. The list now becomes

```
A -> B -> D -> null
```

Traversing the list would now print `A,B,D`. The change was made in `B`, but since the `A` holds a reference to `B`, any changes made in and after `B` would be reflected in the traversal starting at `A`.

Comment: okay your example makes sense. How about we say current is at A and I delete B , now current.next becomes C. But The head (A) is still pointing to B right? So I assume returning A would include B too which I intended to delete. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you "delete" `B`, you basically set `A.next = C`, and (optionally) release the memory used by `B`. So `A` won't be pointing to `B` anymore

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lfcr39w/1/

This is what I have in my mind. Can you point out where I am getting it wrong?