# LeetCode Remove Nth Node From End of List - Linked List

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I came across this answer on LeetCode for the "Remove Nth Node From End of List" Linked List Problem.
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/discuss/524116/JavaScript-One-Pass-Two-Pointer

I understand why I need to update `curr.next` to `curr.next.next`. But I don't understand how this change modifies the `head` too. I thought `curr` was just a variable.

How does changing `curr` changes the `head` too?

Comment: It can modify head (in the code `head = head.next` if the hare ran off the end of the list).

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72503275/how-does-returning-the-head-gives-me-the-result-in-a-linkedlist

Comment: curr.next.next is not necessary.. firstly clear the concept of linked list... Build you own logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand how this change modifies the head too. I thought `curr` was just a variable.

If this assignment were an assignment to `curr` you'd be right, and it wouldn't mutate the list, but the assignment is not to `curr`, but to `curr.next`, and *that* is not a variable, but an attribute of a node in your list. By assigning to that attribute, you effectively mutate that node, and by consequence the list.